# Codeigniter redirect add dynamic 3rd URI segment

Tags: codeigniter

I'd like to get this to redirect to `welcome/stats/3` asuming `site_id` is `3`

```
function add_keyword()
{
    $data = array(
        'keyword' => $this->input->post('keywords'),
        'depth' => $this->input->post('depth'),
        'site_id' => $this->input->post('site_id')
    );

    $site_id = $this->input->post('site_id');

    $this->site_model->add_keyword($data);
    redirect('welcome/stats/', $site_id); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to concatenate `$site_id`, not pass it as a second parameter:

```
redirect('welcome/stats/' . $site_id);
```

Comment: it  wouldn't let me because you answered so quick said i had to wait 5 mins